# Magento: change format url languages switcher

Tags: magento

Whene i change the languages in magento , the url displayed is  bellow :

http://xxxxxx.xx/?___store=english&___from_store=default , so my question is change this to

be like this  http://xxxxx.xx/en/.......

Please can you propose me how to do this in magento ?

Comment: please any sugestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly go to admin panel System -> Configuration
Under Configuration -> Web -> Url options and change ‘Add Store Code to Urls’ to ‘Yes’.

Then change template file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/page/switch/languages.phtml line 50 (or similar destination for your custom theme)

```
<a href="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>
```

to

```
<a href="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl(false) ?>
```

Comment: I can't find System -> Configuration Under Configuration -> Web -> Url options and change ‘Add Store Code to Urls’ to ‘Yes’    in my magento

Comment: can you tell me where is this exactly because i can't find it ? please

Comment: Log in to your Magento admin site. Among menu above there is "System" - drop-down menu. Select: System/Configuration. On the left side you find: General/Web. Now you will see "Url options" on the right. Change ‘Add Store Code to Urls’.
If you can't see System menu then I can assume that your account is not privileged enough. What is your Magento version?
If you can't see System menu than I can assume that your account doesn't have full privilegis.

Comment: Great , Great , Great , thanks my friend (magento Supprot Team ) ,  this exactly what i want really you saved me :)